# BigQuery Schedule Query Notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to get the result of my schedule query as soon as it completes, Big Query scheduler API provide `pub-sub` notification but the message doesn't contain anything about the result.

There is a consumer service which is waiting for the schedule query result we want to notify the consumer service once we have result ready and the service can start consuming it, How we can achieve this ?

The result is stored in the table but there are multiple schedule queries writing the result to the same table, so consumer service, can't just read my table as we need have some offset.
So any help regarding this ?

Comment: I am a little confused with your question, do you want to notify the external service to start reading the data from big query table as soon as your schedule query that load data into the table is completed? I quite didnt understand "The result is stored in the table but there are multiple schedule queries writing the result to the same table, so consumer service, can't just read my table as we need have some offset", Do you want the service to read only the data that is loaded by your schedule query?? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions:

- With scheduled queries, natively, if a consumer expect the result of a specific scheduled queries (and don't care about the others), create a topic dedicated to this scheduled query and plug the consumer on this topic.
- The other solution is to use [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) instead of scheduled queries. With this design, Workflow performs a query with the [dedicated connectors](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/bigquery/Overview), and when the query is over, Workflow calls the consumer (or publish a message in PubSub with the correct attribute to let the consumers filter on the message they want.)

Comment: Can you please explain your 1 approach ? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-run-notifications?_ga=2.243943749.-1161131259.1626670466#turning_on_notifications

Comment: I was checking above article it only send the notification to pubs no query result

Comment: You will never have the query result. Save it in a temporary table and notify the consumer process to look into this table to get the result

Comment: Since there may be many schedule queries writing it to the same table is there any way which we have offset where to consume since we are using `WRITE_APPEND` in schedule queries

Comment: Hmm, do you want only the data added by the Scheduled query? If so, why do you need to aggregate all the row in the same table? Do you have another process which need all the data (whatever are the scheduled queries which added the data)?

Comment: Yes we want the data added by the scheduled query. The reason why we are doing this to keep the past record for the scheduled queries, since we have large amount of scheduled queries which run every hours so having separate table will be difficult to manage. So any insight on this ?

Comment: Did you think your table organisation with views and materialized views? i think it could simplify what you want to achieve.